# Our city has 40 citizens. Our well has 114 water rations left. What gives?

Tags: die2nite

Does that mean that if no one screws up and everybody gets his daily ration, our water sources will be depleted in 2.85 more days? (The city started existing less than a day ago at 23:36.)

Even if we all took 1 water ration every 3 days (unlikely) that only is enough to last for 9 days -- not to forget that banished people also get to get their daily ration.

Is this true? Could there be other sources of water in the map? Are we going to have to kill each other to survive?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is here...

Comment: @Nick clarified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the main construction sites you have to consider making in the game is the Pump. The Pump not only provides you with some opportunities to further improve your town's defenses with the strongest traps in the game, but also allows your town to obtain more water through upgrades. Through this mechanism, you'll be able to survive beyond four days even if nobody dies, and with good teamwork you should be able to avoid having to kill each other off to avoid dehydration.

Furthermore, it's possible to find Jerry Cans on the map, which, when purified using a Water Purifier Tablet, provide 2-10 extra rations of water that are immediately added to the town well.

I wouldn't stave off taking your water ration each day unless you're completely unsure with what you're doing with your AP; if your town's organized, you will get that Pump up.